# how to specify the .flowconfig file location?

Tags: flowtype

When I run flow to type check other JS code, I want to keep the ".flowconfig" configuration file in a fixed place instead of inside of the checked codebase. But I failed to find an option by typing `flow --help`. Does anyone know how to specify a configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/#where-to-put-the-flowconfig-)

You need to run flow in the directory where the config is located. But it's possible to configure the .flowconfig file so it will point to the directory outside of the directory where it's located.

By the way, I don't think it's a good idea to keep the .flowconfig outside the checked codebase. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: We run flow against multiple third-party packages and like to keep the configuration file at a fixed place instead of copying it to the code base of individual packages every time.

Comment: We actually have the same request for files under the flow-typed directory. Is there a way to config Flow such that it only builds up types from libraries once and can be used on scanning multiple third-party packages?

Comment: Why not check all the packages at once running flow in a root directory?

Comment: "Why do you want to do it?": Freedom, un-opinionated layout, the program does follow me and not myself the program, I do control the behaviour of the program and not the opposite, year 2020, ... -;)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to Lou's question,

I wish to use the following directory structure:

```
my_project
├── build
|   └── flow
├── config
|   └── .flowconfig
├── src
|
```

where all code files lie inside the `src` directory.

I do not wish `.flowconfig` to be under any of `my_project` or `src` directories but under `config` one.

Do I have the **freedom** to get that layout, and if "**Yes**" how? *Tia*